# Does Reputation cap considered votes even after serial voting reversed

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, serial-voting, daily-reputation-limit

Yesterday, I was serially upvoted. Naturally, those votes were correctly reversed.

However, I was at loss of reputation as reputation points were not considered during the latter part of day.

Does reputation cap consider votes even after serial voting is reversed? Is the system flawed or this intentional?

[image]

Comment: I think the next time you get a full recalc that'll correct itself, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes calculating the running denormalized tallies of reputation is particularly challenging, for example in your case.

Running a manual recalc of your user seems to have fixed it, you have +225 rep for yesterday (great job!)